# Javascript function context

Tags: javascript

I created a simple moving particles with canvas.

Code :

```
var c = document.getElementById('game'),
    ctx = c.getContext('2d');
var Particle = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = 'tomato';
}
Particle.prototype.update = function(i) {
    console.log(p.length);
    this.x++;
    this.y++;
    if (this.y > 400) {
        p.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
var p = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    p.push(new Particle(i * 10, i * 50));
}
Particle.prototype.render = function() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 3, 0, 2 *
        Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        p[i].update(i);

        // STATEMENT 1
        p[i].render();
        // STATEMENT 2
        Particle.prototype.render.call(
            p[i]);
    }
}
```

First of all Both STATEMENT 1 ND STATEMENT 2 calls render function.
My question is for STATEMENT 1 ,it displays a console error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined
```

but STATEMENT 2 works fine without any error.Can I know the reason ??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Seems to work fine here. Is this the exact same code? Or edited for StackOverflow a little? I'd expect `update` to fail in the same way if there was an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You've got update modifying the contents of p while you're iterating through it.  This is generally a bad idea, and it is causing your problem.

Since you're splicing elements out of the array, but the time the array finishes iterating in the draw function, the object is no longer there.  So, you get to p[i], which may no longer exist.  Worse, your update array is asking for an index, which you're not passing.

The easiest thing to do is to reverse how you're iterating through the array:

```
for (var i = p.length; i > 0; --i) {
    // cache a copy in case it goes away.
    var pPoint = p[i];
    // still bad form.
    pPoint.update(i);
    pPoint.render();
}
```

Overall though, I think you may have more issues than this.